# extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr on using cases

Tags: packages, cases

I'm using the [cryptocode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode?lang=en) package for typesetting a crytographic protocol. However, when I try using cases, I get an error saying 
extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

How do I correct this? Here is the relevant code.

```
\procedure{Example} {%  
s_{i} = \begin{cases} r_{i} & if\,c[i]=0\\ r_{i}-x & otherwise \end{cases} 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE (full minimal compilable example) to help us help you.

Comment: @TeXnician posted MWE!

Comment: That's no MWE. Follow [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/124577) link to see what I meant. It should especially be compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cryptocode` package changes the meaning of `\\` inside its macros.

Use `\tabularnewline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cryptocode}

\begin{document}

\procedure{Example} {%
s_{i} =
  \begin{cases}
  r_{i} & \text{if $c[i]=0$} \tabularnewline
  r_{i}-x & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
}

\end{document}
```

Note that words in math should be properly treated as `\text`.

[image]

### Update

A change in `cryptocode.sty` makes *every* nested alignment to break. Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cryptocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@pc@syntaxhighlight}{#1}{{#1}}{}{}% <--- missing braces around #1
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\procedure{Example} {%
s_{i} =
  \begin{cases}
  r_{i} & \text{if $c[i]=0$} \tabularnewline
  r_{i}-x & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this solution does not work any more. If I try to compile it, I get the following error message: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12. }

Comment: @RomanLangrehr Yes, a (faulty) change in `cryptocode`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a new problem, which is why @egreg's answer doesn't work in my case, whenever the crpytocode procedure contains more than one line. For example, the following example fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cryptocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@pc@syntaxhighlight}{#1}{{#1}}{}{}% <--- missing braces around #1
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\procedure{Example} {%
    a = b \\
    c
}

\end{document}
```

It fails with the error message "Missing } inserted".

However, totally disabling the (mostly unused) automatic syntax highlighting function via the following workaround does:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pc@syntaxhighlight}[1]{#1}
\makeatother
```