Using "cases" inside of cryptocode pseudocodeblock
I'm trying to use "cases" (from the amsmath package) inside of a "pseudocodeblock" (from the cryptocode package). However, this causes errors, apparently because of a clash between how the two packages handle alignment. Is there a way to use cases inside of a pseudocodeblock?
Here's a small example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% Works fine.
\[
x := \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if something} \\
1 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\]

% Works fine.
\pseudocodeblock{
x := 0
}

% Doesn't work/causes errors.
\pseudocodeblock{
x := \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if something} \\
1 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}

\end{document}


Did you try wrapping it in an pcmbox, as described in sec. 3.10 of the manual?

@dg': That doesn't work.

This works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634370/29873

It does! Thanks!
